# Create group identifier from two vectors in matlab

Tags: matlab, unique, identifier

I would like to create a unique group identifier vector (G) based on the values in two column vectors (A and B).

```
A = [1; 1; 1; 2; 2; 1; 1; 2; 2]
B = [1; 1; 2; 1; 2; 1; 1; 1; 2]
```

I would like G to look like this:

```
G = [1; 1; 2; 3; 4; 1; 1; 3; 4]
```

This is probably something simple, but I just can't seem to find the command(s) to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple indeed. You need to use [`unique(...'rows')`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) on vertically stacked input vectors and the third output from it would be your desired output, like so -

```
[~,~,G] = unique([A(:) B(:)],'rows')
```

Comment: This works nicely. I tried unique before but failed to see the additional argument 'rows' which was essential in my case. Thank you!